# User defined filters and sorting options for report builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to allow reports created in report builder 2.0 to give the current user the ability to change the sorting order of data or apply a filter.

For example say I have a report that displays a table with 3 columns.

Report Table

---

|A | B | C |

Is there a way to let the user select any of the 3 columns and sort by ascending or descending order? Can a user filter data in column C, by any of the data that shows up for that particular row? From what I've found via searching and clicking a bunch of buttons in the application it looks like all the filter and sort options have to be built into the report and therefore makes those changes static. It looks like these report can not be modified on the fly when it comes to users filtering data or sorting data.

Can anyone confirm/deny?

Comment: Have you looked at Interactive sorting? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207011(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: @IanPreston, This is exactly what I was looking for. If you submit it as an answer I'll select it. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for replying, much appreciated. Please see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up [Interactive Sorting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207011%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), this allows you to click on a textbox and sort by a specified expression once a report has loaded, which might be enough for you requirements.

Other than that, your only real option is to set up parameters for sorting and filtering and base your sort expression and filtering on the parameter selected, but to you will have to refresh the report for any change in parameter selection to take effect.